# Hot/Cold Observable, 1 subscribers with multiple select query?

Tags: linq, system.reactive

Can 1 Subscriber with multiple select query?

eg:

```
var obj = item.tolist().subscribe(OnNext);

var obj2 = item.where(i=>i.type=="box").subscribe(OnNext);
```

Not sure the code correct or not. but mostly will be like this.
This using 2 subscribe. Can it be only using 1 subscribe?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. Can you please add enough code to make it compile?

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely subscribe the same method to different observables. However, if the subscriber has some state then you need to be aware of concurrency issues because the subscriber may be executing one different threads at the same time. However, this is not a problem unique to Rx and using Rx will help you avoid shared state anyway.

Here is a working example:

```
var observable = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.2)).Take(10);

var projectionA = observable
  .Where(i => i % 2 == 0)
  .Select(i => Tuple.Create("A", i));
var projectionB = observable
  .Select(i => Tuple.Create("B", i));

projectionA.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
projectionB.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
```

I subscribe `Console.WriteLine` to both projections and if you try to execute the code you will see that events from both streams are written to the console.